# How Do I Get Django to Show Image Field From Model in Templates?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get the uploaded image to show in the project template. Here is what my code looks like currently:

projects.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ project.title }} HELLO</h1>
<div class="content-section">
    <div class="media">
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" alt="beach" width=250px height=250px />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>About the project:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
        <br>
        <h5>Technology used:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.tools }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    tools = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to="beach_photos", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from projects.models import Project

def projects(request):
    project = {
       'project':Project.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context = project)
```

settings.py configuration (app is installed)

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When I inspect the image element in the webpage, the source shows up as

src=""

None of the other calls to the model are appearing either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you forgot to add a for-loop in your template. try this:

```
{% for p in project %}
    {{ p.title %}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can I ask how I can identify if I need a for loop to display information vs when I would not? Some of the materials I have been learning from can display without a for loop. Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: yes, in your view you query all projects: Project.objects.all(), so you need to loop over them to show them all. If you only want so show one project, you can query like: Project.objects.all().first(), to show the first project, or Project.objects.all.().filter(pk=1) to show project based on PK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the image field of your record in the database is full.

Access the required model with the `python manage.py shell` command and check if this model has a value of `variable.image.url`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The database was filled. The above reply answered the question. :D